# Internet Explorer times out when using Windows 8.1 VM

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-8.1

When using my virtual machine, I'm trying to gain access to the Internet, but unable to get IE to start, when clicking the icon it doesn't react. I've done some research and a couple of hours troubleshooting, but no luck. It does appear to be a problem for some, but they don't have the exact same problem I do. 
Here's what I've come across while troubleshooting:

1) OS is windows 8.1 32-bit, but my host machine is 64-bit, because of this there might be compatibility issues. Not much more on this though, no explanation on whether that is the problem at all.

2) My network settings could be wrong, but I'm attached to a bridged adapter, my IP's match for both VM and Host, and I can access the web when I use a web browser app (but the app that can't download anything, so I can't download google chrome or the necessary files I need to study).

3) Others say that the problem is Windows 8.1 itself. That VMs just don't work as they should like Windows 7.

I clicked to uninstall Windows explorer, but it seems it doesn't exist, and it doesn't have an icon on the home screen. 
Could it be that the .iso I downloaded did not have IE included?

The original need for the VM was to test Docker containerisation for a report. Should I scrap the whole idea and try for Windows 7 64-bit instead? That's all I can do if I can't find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.